# How to determine whether a matrix is empty or not in matlab?

Tags: matlab

In my matlab program, I want to determine whether a variable or output of a function is empty or not, before going further.

Actually, I've written a function which calculates an intersection point between two line segments. if there is no intersection, the function returns nothing (so the variable assigned by the function will be empty matrix).

I know I could use `size` function but is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html). For instance:

```
>> isempty([])

ans =
     1

>> isempty([42])

ans =
     0
```